# Display a string in xml format on browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a string in my view which is the XML content,when I click a cell on a grid it passes the string value of the cell which is the xml content to the controller through ajax call and now i want it to open in a new tab and display the text as XML. The output should be in xml format with color tags and structure like in xml file but there is no xml file,can we display a string as xml on browser without giving xml file or file path using jquery in view or controller. Any soon help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To have that happen XML has to be the only thing on the page, so you can have the endpoint write to a file when the ajax call is made and then link to the file.

Comment: I have no idea about how to pursue after passing the value to the controller to display it in a new tab and it passes the whole view of the controller to the success function of the ajax call which is not helpful to display the xml content in a new tab in a xml format